# Cropping NSImage with onscreen coordinates incorrect on different screen sizes

Tags: macos, core-graphics, cgrect, quartz

I'm trying to replicate macOS's screenshot functionality, dragging a selection onscreen to provide coordinates for cropping an image. I have it working fine on my desktop Mac (2560x1600), but testing on my laptop (2016 rMBP 15", 2880x1800), the cropped image is completely wrong. I don't understand why I'd get the right results on my desktop, but not on my laptop. I think it has something to do with the Quarts coordinates being different from Cocoa coordinates, seeing as how on the laptop, the resulting image seems like the coordinates are flipped on the Y-axis.

Here is the code I am using to generate the cropping CGRect:

```
# Segment used to draw the CAShapeLayer:
 private func handleDragging(_ event: NSEvent) {
        let mouseLoc = event.locationInWindow

        if let point = self.startPoint,
            let layer = self.shapeLayer {
            let path = CGMutablePath()
            path.move(to: point)
            path.addLine(to: NSPoint(x: self.startPoint.x, y: mouseLoc.y))
            path.addLine(to: mouseLoc)
            path.addLine(to: NSPoint(x: mouseLoc.x, y: self.startPoint.y))
            path.closeSubpath()
            layer.path = path
            self.selectionRect = path.boundingBox
        }
    }

    private func startDragging(_ event: NSEvent) {
        if let window = self.window,
            let contentView = window.contentView,
            let layer = contentView.layer,
            !self.isDragging {

            self.isDragging = true
            self.startPoint = window.mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream

            shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
            shapeLayer.fillColor = NSColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor
            shapeLayer.strokeColor = NSColor.systemGray.cgColor
            layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        }
    }
```

Then this is the code where I actually generate the screenshot and crop using the CGRect:

```
 public func processResults(_ rect: CGRect) {
        if let windowID = self.globalWindow?.windowNumber,
            let screen = self.getScreenWithMouse(), rect.width > 5 && rect.height > 5 {
            self.delegate?.processingResults()

            let cgScreenshot = CGWindowListCreateImage(screen.frame, .optionOnScreenBelowWindow, CGWindowID(windowID), .bestResolution)


            var rect2 = rect
            rect2.origin.y = NSMaxY(self.getScreenWithMouse()!.frame) - NSMaxY(rect);
            
            if let croppedCGScreenshot = cgScreenshot?.cropping(to: rect2) {


                let rep = NSBitmapImageRep(cgImage: croppedCGScreenshot)
                let image = NSImage()
                image.addRepresentation(rep)

                self.showPreviewWindow(image: image)

                let requests = [self.getTextRecognitionRequest()]
                let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: croppedCGScreenshot, orientation: .up, options: [:])

                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                    do {
                        try imageRequestHandler.perform(requests)
                    } catch let error {
                        print("Error: \(error)")
                    }
                }
                
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
                    self.hidePreviewWindow()
                }
            }
        }
        
        self.globalWindow = nil
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 15 minutes after I asked this question, I tried one more thing and it works!

Relevant snippet:

```
var correctedRect = rect

// Set the Y origin properly (counteracting the flipped Y-axis)
correctedRect.origin.y = screen.frame.height - rect.origin.y - rect.height;

// Checks if we're on another screen
if (screen.frame.origin.y < 0) {
    correctedRect.origin.y = correctedRect.origin.y - screen.frame.origin.y
}


// Finally, correct the x origin (if we're on another screen, the origin will be larger than zero)
correctedRect.origin.x = correctedRect.origin.x + screen.frame.origin.x

// Generate the screenshot inside the requested rect
let cgScreenshot = CGWindowListCreateImage(correctedRect, .optionOnScreenBelowWindow, CGWindowID(windowID), .bestResolution)
```