# Covert NSView's mouse down coordinates to screen coordinate system in cocoa Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, coordinates, nsview, nsevent

```
override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        
    let startPoint = event.locationInWindow
    print(startPoint) //for top left it prints (0, 900)
```

To my knowledge the screen's origin is defined as the top left corner of the screen.
But `NSView`'s mouse down event gives the screen's bottom left as the origin(top left coordinates are 0,900).

I have already tried using:

```
  self.convert(event.locationInWindow, from: nil)
```

But the results are the same.

Is there a way to convert these coordinates to screen coordinates?

Comment: In **iOS** the origin is top left, in macOS it's indeed bottom left.

Comment: I see. Either way, I am trying to use the coordinates  to define the screenBounds of ```CGWindowListCreateImage``` in which (according to the documentation) the origin is the top-left corner.

Comment: Hint: mouseLocation.

Comment: According to the documentation```NSEvent.mouseLocation``` is suppose to return the coordinates in "screen coordinates". But I'm still getting the coordinates with respect to bottom left as the origin.

Comment: I guess you may want [isFlipped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/763987/2227743)? It reverses the coordinate system of a view.

Comment: I think isFlipped is a get-only property. Is it not?

Comment: Duplicate of [Cropping NSImage with onscreen coordinates incorrect on different screen sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67442150/cropping-nsimage-with-onscreen-coordinates-incorrect-on-different-screen-sizes)